# How can I calculate the resistance of a complex PCB trace?

Tags: pcb, heater, flexible

[image]

I want to design a flex PCB heater. In the design requirement, there is a value such as 7.5 ohms and 18 watts. When I calculate with copper, my PCB area is not sufficient for the desired resistance value. For this reason, I will have to use alloys such as Inocel 600 and Cupronickel 715, which have higher resistance.

For example, when I select traces in Altium and enter the number of oz of copper used in the layer stack manager, trace length, trace resistance and maximum current carrying information are written on the top right. So, if I use Inocel 600, cupronickel 715 style alloys and define information such as resistivity, how can I measure the resistance of this complex trace? How can I achieve this in applications like Ansys Siwave or other applications?

[image]

Altium has offered an option where we can add the .xml material library for the new material. I think I can learn the attributes of the foil material to be added from your manufacturer, but I do not know how to convert it to xml format.[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

As far as I understand, the maximum current carrying capacity is what the material can carry without burning.

Comment: The resistance depends on the thickness of the copper, which value did you choose? Your Manufacturer may provide values, typical values are 17, 35, 70 and 105µm

Comment: yeap but  thing  you re said that  width of the copper layer, ı wanna add resistivity of the material

Comment: @Electronx that makes no sense, unless your job is to maximize waste of money. Use thinner traces, and copper. Any manufacturer I know of will happily produce 0.3mm wide traces in 35µm thick copper, and 5000 mm of that (as in your example) will have a resistance of 8.2 Ω already, So, problem solved: you can easily fit at least as much trace on your board if its thinner than what you're currently doing.

Comment: Are you sure your current values are correct? I get 1.477 / 1.549 / 1.632 A respectively... And even with 2.5 A those traces should be fine. Remember, you *want* those traces to heat up, otherwise you wont have a heater.

Comment: @PatrickFiedler requirements 7.5 ohms and 18 watts for 50x76mm area, u can see the calculations that ı add,Please criticize me if there is a point that I missed or did not understand .

Comment: @Electronx I'll add a detailed answer later (if noone else is faster) since i'm on the road right now.

Comment: @Electronx a device that fulfills your 18W requirement will always produce 18 W in heat, no matter the material. You're barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes marc, I'm sure there is something I missed or didn't understand, I'm sorry my brain doesn't work that well.

Comment: So 18 W = P = U • I = I•R • I = I² R. With I, according to your specification, being 7.5 A, R = 18 W / (7.5 A)² = 0.32 Ω. So, your whole requirement is wrong. We can't know what your actual requirements are, but we can conclusively say that before you can show the desired resistance cannot be achieved with standard copper, you are working on the wrong problem and need to go back to 9. grade school physics-level electronics basics.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ups requirement is  7.5 ohm for heater  not amp

Comment: Then just exchange variables? I = √(18 W / 7.5 Ω) = 1.55 A, not any more, and especially not 2.64 A, as you claim in a comment. And yes, that makes your trace hot. Exactly as much hotter as any other trace that is part of a 18 W heater, no matter the material.

Comment: yeaps thats right ,sorry for this

Comment: What PCB fab do you have that can do inconel or cupronickel traces? I've never seen a PCB made with anything other than copper.

Comment: Would you consider creating a multi-layer design to achieve the total trace length/resistance? Also, if you consider the heat generated from 18W in a relatively small space (50x76mm), you may want to use a better heat durable flex material such a polyimide. Even that material can be stacked to create multi-layered systems.

Comment: @Hearth I found a few companies that produce in the United States and Europe.

Comment: @Nedd  I thought about making it two-layered, but I'm worried about heat dissipation. I'm currently doing full stack pcb heater tests at Comsol Multiphysics. This is very useful for issues such as heat dissipation, resistance drop, and stretching test. I'm thinking of placing my orders under the sponsorship of the pcb manufacturer and writing a few small articles.

Comment: If the end goal here is to have a flex circuit that acts like a heating element there are loads of manufacturers that offer standard (and custom) components that achieve this. (Just one example: https://www.turboflexheaters.com/standard-rectangle-heaters/  )  If this is more of a personal or theoretical project then continue on. However, if this is a requirement for an actual product design you may want to consider purchasing a known tried and tested solution.

Comment: Thanks for your support Nedd. , I actually want to know the theory behind it. A few customers only wanted me to do the design and production files. However, the resistance value they want has a deviation tolerance of 10%. I can never know or measure this without a prototype.I just question whether I can do this in the best way and I want to add new skills.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in comments, you can push up resistance by using thinner traces.

However, have you checked what temperature the PCB will have to be at to dissipate the proposed power for the given surface area and cooling mode (convective or conductive)?  You might find you need a larger area to dissipate the power at an acceptable surface temperature.

Comment: If it's a heater, spreading out the power to keep the temperature low would be counterproductive. You'd need instead to make sure the PCB material can handle the desired temperatures.

Comment: It depends. In some applications you need a certain power to be delivered, but in a fashion that is compatible with where the heat is being delivered.  For instance, in domestic radiators, you could easily deliver the target power in a much smaller form factor if they ran at very high temperatures, but in general you want them to be touch safe.  Similarly, we spec resistors to dissipate a certain power within a certain maximum temperature.